# Find the last missing value by column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I have a data frame such  as:

```
> set.seed(8)

> A <- rnorm(10, 20)
> B <- rnorm(10, 45)
> C <- rnorm(10, 60)

> test1 <- data.frame(A,B,C)
> test1 <- round(test1, digits = 2)

> test1[sample(1:10, 3, F), 1] <- NA
> test1[sample(1:10, 3, F), 2] <- NA
> test1[sample(1:10, 3, F), 3] <- NA

> test1[11:20, ] <- NA
> test1$date <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('1970-01-01', origin='01-01-1970'),
                   to = as.Date('1970-01-20', origin='01-01-1970'), by=1)
> test1
       A     B     C       date
1  19.92    NA 61.28 1970-01-01
2  20.84 45.29    NA 1970-01-02
3  19.54 45.42    NA 1970-01-03
4  19.45 43.71 60.02 1970-01-04
5  20.74 45.07 61.74 1970-01-05
6  19.89 44.19 58.89 1970-01-06
7     NA    NA 58.94 1970-01-07
8  18.91 44.73    NA 1970-01-08
9     NA    NA 60.60 1970-01-09
10    NA 44.76 57.98 1970-01-10
11    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-11
12    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-12
13    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-13
14    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-14
15    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-15
16    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-16
17    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-17
18    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-18
19    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-19
20    NA    NA    NA 1970-01-20
```

So there are many `NA` at the end (a `NA` "tail") that one may want to eliminate. I've tried finding the first `NA` but I'll bump into a `NA` in the middle of the data frame:

```
 > apply(test1, 2, function(x) which(is.na(x))[1])
   A    B    C date 
   7    1    2   NA 
 > test1$A[8] #As you can see this doesn't give me what I need.
 [1] 18.91
```

The `complete.cases()` function won't help since I don't want to eliminate all rows with missing values. Inverting the data frame and retrieving the first non `NA` should be the way to go here:

```
> apply(test1[nrow(test1):1, ], 2, function(x) which(!is.na(x))[1])

   A    B    C date 
  13   11   11    1
```

After this the column with the smallest number should be used to find the row number that contains the last non completely `NA` row. This leads to:

```
> test1[1:(nrow(test1)-10), ]
```

Which will produce a data frame with no long missing value tail. Although this works I reckon that there is a better/faster way to accomplish this. I'll write a function and wait for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
> colaVA <- function(x){
>   mat <- apply(x[nrow(test1):1, ], 2, function(x) which(!is.na(x))[1])
>   n <- length(mat)
>   m <- sort(mat, partial=n-1)[n-1]
>   x <- x[1:(m-1),]
>  x
> }
> 
> colaVA(test1)

       A     B     C       date
1  19.92    NA 61.28 1970-01-01
2  20.84 45.29    NA 1970-01-02
3  19.54 45.42    NA 1970-01-03
4  19.45 43.71 60.02 1970-01-04
5  20.74 45.07 61.74 1970-01-05
6  19.89 44.19 58.89 1970-01-06
7     NA    NA 58.94 1970-01-07
8  18.91 44.73    NA 1970-01-08
9     NA    NA 60.60 1970-01-09 
10    NA 44.76 57.98 1970-01-10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rle` (run-length encoding) on the indicator for whether a value is missing to identify the row number of the last non-NA value in each column:

```
apply(test1, 2, function(x) {r <- rle(is.na(x)) ; cumsum(r$length)[max(which(!r$value))]})
#    A    B    C date 
#    8   10   10   20
```

Then you can subset however you see fit based on these values.